# Is $f^{-1}$ a manifold?

Tags: general-topology

Given  $M = f^{-1}(0)$ for $f(x,y) = x^2-y^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It is to be shown whether this is a manifold or not.

Pardon my bad understanding of manifolds, but what's the set here?

Is it $M = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|f^{-1}(0) = 0\}$ where $f = x^2-y^2$

Well this runs into various problems: first of $f^{-1}(0)$ is a single point and not a space, secondly I don't happen to find $f^{-1}$ because $f$ is a vector valued function with just one row.

So what am I messing up this time?

Comment: $f^{-1}(0)$ is a shorter notation for $f^{-1}(\{0\})$, i.e. the preimage of the set $\{0\}$ under $f$ (the set consisting of those $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $f(x,y)=0$). It is **not** the image of $0$ under the inverse map $f^{-1}$ (which wouldn't make sense here as $f$ isn't bijective, so the inverse map is not defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M=f^{-1}(0)$, then $f(M)=0$. Therefore

\begin{equation}
M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2| x^2-y^2=0\}.
\end{equation}

You need to show whether this set is a manifold or not.

Comment: Interesting.  $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\;|\; x^2-y^2 = a\}$ is a manifold for any $a \ne 0$, but not for $a=0$.

Comment: can I argue that $(x,y) = 0$ reduces the rank of $(Df)$ from $1$ to $0$ hence it doesn't count as manifold?